# Permission denied to access property "sbh"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Recently a message started to appear every time I am visiting the web interface of Elastic Beanstalk: "Permission denied to access property "sbh"

[image]

However I know no resource that could be named "sbh" and I have administrator access:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

How is it possible that I am denied permission to access a property? How can I find this property?

Comment: I solved it by deactivating the Code Climate extension.